# Run a function from another module in new thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I created a simple plugin system for my application and for now, I want to run each plugin in a new thread.
Here is a part of my code:

```
def newThread(self, f, args=()):
        t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=args)
        t.deamon = True
        t.start()
        return t

print "s"

for mod in imported_modules:
    if 'init' in vars(mod):
        newThread(mod.init, None)

print 1
```

One of my plugins is a TCP server that is listening on the socket . If I run it in the main thread, the application doesn't load other plugins and wait until the server stops!
Also the above code does not run the init function on my plugin.
Now the question is:
How to call an external function in a new thread ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Threading in CPython has known pitfalls. It would be helpful if you included some code that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: I don't get it. Can't you run your TCP server in a separate thread as well?

Comment: @freakish The tcp server is okay! The `newThread` cannot run a function from another module

Comment: @SoroushKhosravi Why not? What's the error? And why are you passing `None` to `newThread`? It should be a sequence. `None` will definitely throw an exception. And isn't `newThread` a method of an object? Where's the object? You have to give us full code.

Comment: @freakish There is not any error or exception. Just nothing done by the method! The init method from my plugin does not call...

Comment: @SoroushKhosravi It doesn't matter whether it is an external function or not. If it doesn't work, then it means that it does not go inside `newThread` function. So the code snippet you've shown us is ok. The problem is somewhere else. For example: what is `imported_modules`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when we are trying to create a new thread, we should pass args to the method we want to call it in new thread. If it doesn't get any params, we should pass it an empty tuple like this:

```
newThread(mod.init, ())
```